# JQuery preventDefault() is stopping subsequent function

Tags: jquery, forms, onclick, return-value, preventdefault

I am using the preventDefault function to stop my form from submitting. This is working fine, however following that function I have a onClick function which is no longer working.

Strangely, before the onclick function I do have a simple div centering function which is working even following the form preventDefault.

**Edit: I found the issue, the onclick function was for an item that was loaded via ajax in the first function. so the selector was probably not finding it**

Below is my code:

```
    // Submit zip code
    $("#get_zip").submit(function (zip)  
    { 
    //Send zipcode
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_calls.php",
            data: "zip="+$('#zip').val()+"&send_zip=true",
            success: function(listing){$("#wrapper").html(listing);  $("#lightbox,#welcome").fadeOut(300);},
            error: function(){alert(3);$("#error").text("Could not retrieve posts").fadeIn(300).delay(900).fadeOut(300)}
        });

    //Stop form submission action
     zip.preventDefault();

    }); 

  //Center item box
       $("#item").centerInClient();


    //When clicking an item row
    $("tr.item").click(function()  
    { 

    // Get item id from selected row id
    var id = $(this).attr('id');


    //Fill item box with item details
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_calls.php",
            data: "id="+id+"&get_item=true",
            success: function(r){$("#item_detail").html(r);  $("#lightbox, #item").fadeIn(300);},
            error: function(){alert(2);$("#error").text("Could not retrieve posts").fadeIn(300).delay(900).fadeOut(300)}
        });
    });
```

Any Help on this would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm trying to use ajax too with a prevent.default. But it stops working within the ajax!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
zip.preventDefault();
```

to:

```
return false;
```

I think that `preventDefault()` is bubbling up and canceling your click handler.

Comment: I actually initially tried using return false, but that gives me the same problem. thanks for answering though